# How to restart my server automatically using crontab if they went down?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a jar file which I am running like this in my Ubuntu 10.10 and then it starts my exhibitor server in the background -

```
nohup java \
    -jar /pekooz/exhibitor-1.5.1/lib/exhibitor-1.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
    -c file --fsconfigdir /opt/exhibitor/conf \
    --hostname machineA > exhibitor.out &
```

Now I am trying to use `crontab` to check whether my exhibitor server is running or not. If it is not running, then start it again so I decided to use crontab and I did the below steps to setup crontab -

1. Created a new crontab by running `crontab -e`.
2. Added this line to the file that just opened

   ```
   */5 * * * * pgrep -f exhibitor || nohup java -jar /pekooz/exhibitor-1.5.1/lib/exhibitor-1.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar -c file --fsconfigdir /opt/exhibitor/conf --hostname machineA > exhibitor.out
   ```
3. Save the file and exit the editor.

So for the testing purpose to see whether my crontab is working or not, I started my exhibitor server like this firstly -

```
$ nohup java \
    -jar ./exhibitor-1.5.1/lib/exhibitor-1.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
    -c file --fsconfigdir /opt/exhibitor/conf \
    --hostname machineA > exhibitor.out &
[1] 14401

$ nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

And then I setup my crontab as shown above with the steps. After that I did `kill -9 14401` so that I can see whether my exhibitor server is getting restarted automatically by crontab or not. And apparently, they didn't get started up and I don't see any error as well. Below is the log -

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
Nov  5 17:21:45 machineA crontab[12755]: (cronusapp) BEGIN EDIT (cronusapp)
Nov  5 17:23:17 machineA crontab[12755]: (cronusapp) END EDIT (cronusapp)
Nov  5 17:25:01 machineA CRON[13671]: (root) CMD (  puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/motd-stats.pp >>$PUPPET_LOG 2>&1)
Nov  5 17:25:01 machineA CRON[13672]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov  5 17:25:01 machineA CRON[13673]: (cronusapp) CMD (pgrep -f exhibitor || nohup java -jar /pekooz/exhibitor-1.5.1/lib/exhibitor-1.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar -c file --fsconfigdir /opt/exhibitor/conf --hostname machineA > exhibitor.out)
Nov  5 17:25:01 machineA postfix/pickup[2345]: 2B0D8819F9: uid=78402 from=<cronusapp>
Nov  5 17:25:01 machineA postfix/cleanup[13679]: 2B0D8819F9: message-id=<20141106002501.2B0D8819F9@machineA.domain.host.com>
Nov  5 17:25:01 machineA postfix/qmgr[25623]: 2B0D8819F9: from=<cronusapp@machineA.domain.host.com>, size=814, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  5 17:25:01 machineA postfix/local[13681]: 2B0D8819F9: to=<cronusapp@machineA.domain.host.com>, orig_to=<cronusapp>, relay=local, delay=0.11, delays=0.07/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Nov  5 17:25:01 machineA postfix/qmgr[25623]: 2B0D8819F9: removed
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why my crontab is not working? I just need to restart my exhibitor server automatically if they went down somehow.

Comment: You might want to look into using [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to launch your process: you can tell upstart to "respawn" your program if it dies.

Comment: @glennjackman I am running Ubuntu 10.10 which has no support whatsoever. I have already tried and some of the commands doesn't work.

Comment: Then perhaps a simple wrapper: `sh -c 'while true; do java -jar ...; done'`

Comment: @Patrick I was not able to understand what you said? :(

Comment: He's saying that whatever you're using to run the exhibitor app, wrap it in a while true block. `sh -c 'while true; do java -jar ...; done'`. This will act like a guard which will constantly keep restarting exhibitor every time it dies.

Comment: What is the content of the email that cron sent you? It contains the output from the job, which should be a big clue as to what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Is `java` in `/usr/bin` directory? The `crontab` has a minimal `PATH` by default.  You may have to set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` in your crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/latest;export JAVA_HOME; \
    PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin; \
    pgrep -f exhibitor || nohup java \
    -jar /pekooz/exhibitor-1.5.1/lib/exhibitor-1.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
    -c file --fsconfigdir /opt/exhibitor/conf --hostname machineA > exhibitor.out
```

Comment: Yes java is in `/usr/bin`. This is what I got `/usr/bin/java` after I did `which java`. And what is this `/opt/java/latest` in your suggestion.

Comment: Some bizarre installations put java in strange places.  Not familiar with Ubuntu, so that was partially a shot in the dark.